# How to share an stl file?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about slicing. If I just describe the problem I would expect my question will be closed since the users have no way to reproduce the issue.

Is there a way to share the stl file I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe share it on pastebin or github? We don't have a specific way to share a whole STL file. I've often thought that we could do with a sharing mechanism similar to that used on the Blender site, which is blender-exchange.com. See [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/14005) for more info about that. I'm not sure how one would go about creating an "stl-exchange" though.

However, see [this comment](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/how-to-upload-a-blend-file-on-bse-good-practices-and-advice#comment6973_3050) and the [following comment](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/how-to-upload-a-blend-file-on-bse-good-practices-and-advice#comment6974_3050):

> I'd argue that 90-99% of uploaded files on Blend Exchange are a waste. They could either have been replaced with a couple of screenshots, a diagram, a short gif or a more accurate description.

So, bearing that in mind, do you *really* need to share the whole STL file to illustrate the issue, or is there a Minimal Reproducible Example that you could use instead?

Comment: Well, usually on other SE sites, when I post screenshots or don't upload a file they downvote or even close my question. And usually they don't like pastebin/github since they are temporary.

Comment: I'm going to post the question. Hoping I don't deserve downvotes.

Comment: Please note that screenshots of code or text are frowned upon, because images are not text-searchable. Temporary file storage is also not good, as once the link to the file is broken, then the question is probably useless without the file, and therefore useless to others. Gists on github need not be temporary and could be useful as a file storage